# Determining Japanese AC Delco manufacturing date

Tags: battery

I understand from [Interpreting AC Delco's manufacturing date for car batteries](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18888/interpreting-ac-delcos-manufacturing-date-for-car-batteries?newreg=9ddeda866c484fd49fe6af2038a1826b) and other posts that the manufacturing date for AC Delco batteries is encoded in text on the top sticker starting with 'P' or 'S'. However, I can't see any codes matching this on my battery.

The only codes on the top are '19', and 'Dk 84911'. On the side appears to be IHR31. See photos below.

Is there a different standard for Japanese batteries?

[image: Label]
[image: More label]
[image: Battery side]

Comment: Probably check out a japanese site...

Comment: I figured that since AC Delco are an American manufacturer that there may be some English-language resources. My Japanese is a bit rusty (and I did Google for this - in English - but failed to find anything useful).

Comment: Go for those very clear japanese characters ... but I don't think english sites will help much

Comment: That says 'Hydrometer', but nice guess!

Comment: So all those characters say hygrometer... or just one...

Comment: Those are the characters from the second photo. The ones around the white box in the first photo are for people to write the installation date, mileage, etc.

Comment: The three characters mean hydrometer, according to Google Translate. Some other site suggested that there can be an additional round sticker - so unless that's just missing?

Comment: I had that worked out 15 minutes ago as I saw "km" bottom right of the lower white rectangle :)